# Access Oracle Database using IP address: The network adapter could not establish the connection

Tags: oracle, oracle18c

I'm currently exploring Oracle database as a possible alternate server to MS SQL.

Unfortunately, Im stuck in a particular step.

1. Installed Oracle 18c
2. Installed SQL Developer to connect to database
3. Successfully Connected to Oracle db using localhost as host name
4. updated listener.ora and tnsnames.ora and replaced localhost to the actual ip address
5. tried to connect using ip address in SQL Developer got the error:
   The network adapter could not establish the connection
6. updated listener.ora and tnsnames.ora and replaced ip address to host name
7. Same error

This is installed in a Windows 10 Environment

Note: SQL Developer and Oracle db are installed in the same server. This is to first test if I can connect using IP

Comment: Does both are installed in same machine

Comment: @T.H.E. Tech Savvy Yes. For now im testing it on the same server. Once ok will test it on pc outside the local pc

Comment: Is it working fine in your local

Comment: If i use localhost yes. But if I use the ip address no, i get the error specified in step number 5 in my question

Comment: Can you show the configuration which you did in two ora files

Comment: Does your ipaddress pinging by itself?

Comment: @T.H.E.TechSavvy solved it. please see my answer bellow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solve the issue by doing the following steps:

1. Run powershell as Administrator
2. Run lsnrctl stop, lsnrctl start, lsnrctl reload to refresh services
3. Tried to connect again and gave me a "The TNS Listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor" error
4. Added orcl in SID_List in listner.ora
5. Run lsnrctl stop, lsnrctl start, lsnrctl reload to refresh services
6. And can now access both in local and outside the pc.

Thanks